# How to use fluid simulation to combine different meshes for 3d printing

Tags: mesh, fluid-simulation, 3d-printing, stl

I'm trying to 3d print a hollowed version of the bust of a video-game character.
The character is very detailed and has meshes for every part of armor and a single eye is composed of 4 different meshes.
I've seen that in older blender version it was possible by using the fluid simulation like explained
in this video, where a multimesh object was "approximated" by its' fluid sim in blender.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K-l2XAkZxVg

I've tried to apply the domain fluid mode to the external cube and the fluid -> flow mode to the mesh at no avail. I don't seem to be able to see any change in the original mesh.

[image: Model mesh settings]

[image: Domain mesh settings]

Comment: So the end goal is one solid 3d printable mesh?

Comment: Yes the idea would be to remove all fancy "internals" of the model and only have a closed even if complex external shell.

Comment: You might try the voxel remesh tool

Comment: Thank you, it sounds promising!